# Are Konica and Minolta lenses interchangeable?

Tags: old-lenses, 35mm, lens-mount, minolta, konica

I have an old Konica FS-1 35mm SLR camera with quite a nice F1.8 lens on, but I'd like to use a different body (without a battery pounding auto wind on mechanism!).  There seem to be plenty of Minolta cameras on ebay, but relatively few Konica ones.  I know that Minolta bought out Konica at some point, but are the lenses from these ~30/40 year old cameras still interchangeable?

Comment: Some interesting detail here: http://www.buhla.de/Foto/Konica/eHexanonHaupt.html (it's in English)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but no -- a Konica FS-1 uses a different mount than either the Minolta MC/MD or the A mount.

Konica did buy out Minolta, but this was quite a while after the FS-1, FT-1, etc., had been discontinued. They also sold the Minolta camera division off to Sony *quite* soon after acquiring Minolta. As far as I know, there was never any work done on creating any sort of adapter to allow any compatibility between the two completely separate camera lines (and when Sony bought it, they got the Minolta camera division, but as far as I know, the old Konica camera division was long gone, so they didn't acquire any rights to it at all).

Comment: Aww that's a shame - I'll have to keep looking then. Thanks for the interesting background info too!

Comment: It is kind of -- I have a couple of old Konica lenses and both Minolta and Sony cameras I'd like to use together as well.